# angular2: apply class to d3 element from component's style

Tags: d3.js, angular, typescript

Having a component in angular2 where `app.component.css` defines class `h-bar`:

[image]

In `app.component.ts`, d3 is used to generate elements which applies the class `h-bar` from `app.component.css`.

```
d3.select("#container").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <- C
                .data(data) // <- D
                .enter() // <- E
                .append("div") // <- F                
                .attr("class", "h-bar")                
                .append("span"); // <- G
```

However the style has NOT been rendered properly. Looking into the html generated, i found that random **_ngcontent-baf-1** (not sure if it is `module.id`) is missing from those elements generated by `d3`.

[image]

So that i would like to add this attribute `module.id` to these element:

```
// Enter
            d3.select("#container").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <- C
                .data(data) // <- D
                .enter() // <- E
                .append("div") // <- F          
                .attr(module.id, "")                      
                .attr("class", "h-bar")                
                .append("span"); // <- G
```

Unfortunately the error was thrown as `module.id` is invalid attribute name:

[image]

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulated styles will only work for DOM objects handled by Angular.

I'd suggest turning off encapsulation on this component:

```
@Component({
  ...,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

however, this will pollute your global CSS namespace, so your ids/classes should be unique to this component.

To keep encapsulation, try this:

```
  constructor(private hostRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngContentId = '_ngcontent-' + this.hostRef.nativeElement.attributes[1].name.substr(8);
  }

  addStuff(){
    d3.select("#container").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <- C
      .data(data) // <- D
      .enter() // <- E
      .append("div") // <- F          
      .attr(this.ngContentId, "")
      .attr("class", "h-bar")
      .append("span"); // <- G 
  }
```

This is quick and dirty, I don't know, if the host id is always `attributes[1]`. It might vary, so you'd have to loop through the attributes to find the right one.

Comment: The css is working however `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` will take the `module.id` out.

Comment: out of what? I don't see a connection between `moduleId` and `encapsulation` edit: I see now. `_ngcontent-baf-1` is not `module.id`. `module.id` is basically the path of the component.  `_ngcontent-baf-1` is used to provide view encapsulation / emulate shadow dom.

Comment: sorry i mean `_ngcontent-baf-1`. any way to generate element using angular `ngFor` then bind d3 data model for each element. i still want to keep the beauty of encapsulation?

Comment: You could inject ComponentRef and get the native element's attributes. Find the one that starts with `_nghost-`, e.g. `_nghost-abc-1` and then apply the `_ngcontent-abc-1` attribute to your d3 generated elements

Comment: i use `Angular` to generate element and associate with data with `d3.datum`

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is the component id `ngvontent...` is missing when appending by `d3`. So `angular` is used to generate them first. Then `d3` is used to associate data and render the rest. Btw thanks for your help.